# Filter Object Array 1 on the basis on 2nd Object Array in Javascript(UnderscoreJS)

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I wanted to filter Object Array 1 if it's object value not exist in 2nd object Array. Non-Intersected values from 2nd array

```
> aaa = [{id:1, name:"abc"}, {id:2, name:"xyz"}], 
> bbb = [{group:1}, {group:4}]

> result should be [{id:2, name:"xyz"}]

_.filter(aaa, function(a){
    return _.find(bbb, function(b){
        return b.id !== a.group;
    });
});
```

But the result is using this code is wrong. please help me here

Comment: For something as simple, please provide a runnable snippet.

Comment: Do you really want to use underscore? This is quite heavier than vanilla js for that kind of things.

Comment: @MaheerAli it is mentioned in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution based on underscore.

`b.id !== a.group` -> `a.id !== b.group` to match your objects' structure.

Then, 
`a.id !== b.group` -> `a.id === b.group` and negate the find result, to filter your object properly ;)

```js
const aaa = [{id:1, name:"abc"}, {id:2, name:"xyz"}];
const bbb = [{group:1}, {group:4}];

const result = _.filter(aaa, function(a){
    return !_.find(bbb, function(b){
        return a.id === b.group;
    });
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It returns all values of array aaa not filtered.

Comment: @ZaidIqbal what? Did you click on the **Run code snippet** button? It actually return what you expect (`[{id:2, name:"xyz"}]`).

Comment: Oh ok.. actually i am checking it with my actual data set

Answer (score 1):

With lodash you could use [`_.reject`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#reject), which excludes the items who are found. This is opposite of [`_.filter`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#filter)

> ```
> _.reject(collection, [predicate=_.identity])
> ```

```js
var aaa = [{ id: 1, name: "abc" }, { id: 2, name: "xyz" }],
    bbb = [{ group: 1 }, { group: 4 }],
    result = _.reject(aaa, ({ id }) => _.find(bbb, ({ group }) => group === id));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Instead of using `find` in every iteration, you could take the unwanted `id` in a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and check against for filtering.

```js
var aaa = [{ id: 1, name: "abc" }, { id: 2, name: "xyz" }],
    bbb = [{ group: 1 }, { group: 4 }],
    groups = new Set(bbb.map(({ group }) => group)),
    result = aaa.filter(({ id }) => !groups.has(id));

console.log(result);
```